# dependency injection via container

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, interface, containers, autofac

In Xamarin.Forms I have a simple container (of AutoFac, but it can be any other container) with only 2 mappings:

```
static class BootStrap
    {
        public static IContainer Configure()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<MainPageViewModel>().As<IMainPageViewModel>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<MainPage>().As<IMainPage>().SingleInstance();

            return builder.Build();

        }
    }
```

This is the MainPage class, which includes a ctor, with an IMainPageViewModel parameter:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, IMainPage
    {
        private IMainPageViewModel _mainPageViewModel;
        public MainPage(IMainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mainPageViewModel = mainPageViewModel;
        }

    }
```

This is the MinPageViewModel class:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IMainPageViewModel
{

}
```

In order to establish the mappings I use this App class

```
 public App()
 {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NiceMasterDetailPage();
            BootStrap.Configure();
 }
```

The error I get is that I don't have a default ctor for MainPage, but I don't want to use the default ctor for MainPage.
I want to use a ctor which has an interface as its parameter - this is how Dependency Injection should work. Does someone have an idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? If so then mark the provided solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve the desired page via the container instead of trying to initialize it manually

```
//...

IContainer  container;

public App() {
    InitializeComponent();

    container = BootStrap.Configure();

    MainPage = container.Resolve<MainPage>();        
}

//...
```

That way the container will inject any dependencies of the type being resolved